# How to encrypt url in javascript and decrypt in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, encryption

```
var url = "DocumentId="+DocumentID+"&SectionType=1&RecID="+RecipientID;
window.open ( "../EBox/ShowLetter.aspx?Url="+encodeURIComponent(url),'PrintMail' , features );
```

Instead of encoding I want ot encrypt the url . What is the solution for this?

Comment: If it has to be secure, javascript is the wrong place to go. Anything done in javascript will be visible to a hacker, who will easily get an encrypted string.

Comment: @Neb, you should post your comment as answer because this is **the** answer to this question.

Comment: its not true - the algorithm you use to encrypt needs to be secure, not that the source code is visible.

Comment: @Chii, and could you explain which is this secure algorithm? All of them require keys, pass phrases, certificates, initialization vectors which need to be stored somewhere. Where would you store them in case of javascript?

Comment: Anything that can be decrypted is insecure when you have source code from javascript. Obviously, there is nothing 100% secure over the internet, but you just have to settle for some level of security.

Comment: the real question is, what is the thread model? are you trying to prevent the user from seeing the URL (but still post to it on the client side)? or are you trying to prevent spam bots from seeing it? or some third party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has to be secure, javascript is the wrong place to go. Anything done in javascript will be visible to a hacker, who will easily get an encrypted string.

Comment: +1, that's exactly how it is.

Comment: +1 Further: Anything done on a user device (whether deployed application onto a mobile, desktop, or in the browser) can eventually be modified by the user.  Never trust anything from a user device.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTP with SSL (HTTPS). Everything sent between the client and the server (including the URL in the HTTP GET request) will be encrypted.

Obviously, this won't hide the data from the user, but since it starts in unencrypted form in the browser (the data you were planning to input into the JS encryption routine), nothing will.